# Spoken English for direction of a Road

Tags: grammar, american-english, spoken-english

I try to solve a map by reading a transcript of the map.

Map

[image]

Here I share just one part of the transcript for The Reynolds House

The sheepmarket is one of the main centers for art and history in the whole country. If you look at our map, you'll see some of the main attraction there. Most visitors start from Crawley Road, at the bottom of the map. The Reynolds House is one of the oldest house in the city, and is open to the public. It's on the north side of Crawaley Road, next to the footpath that leads to the public gardens

As per the direction The Reynolds House is H.

Can anyone helps me to understand why it is H? I also draw some red arrows over the picture. I want to know the possible name of those roads as they are not given in the map.

I believe the arrowed road behind **C** is Hill Road but then again I thought why is not it Crawley Road?

Comment: It's not clear why locations on the map are marked with letters, but the key uses numbers. Of course it's not possible to deduce the names of streets if they are not given on the map.

Comment: Letters represent the missing locations that need to find out.

Comment: I see now that it's an exercise. H matches the description of the location of the Reynolds House. The streets surrounding Station Square would probably have the address Station Square, but it's impossible to guess what the short street leading to Hill Road might be called.

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with the English language. The streets you put arrows on are not named on the map or in the text.

Comment: There is only one letter shown on the north side of Crawley road, and that is H. The text describes "Reynolds House" as being on the north side of Crawley, so it must be H.

Comment: Note also that the "arrowed road behind C" can't be Crawley road, because "Crawley road" is clearly marked at the bottom of the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, Crawley Road is clearly marked on the map, and there is only one house marked on the map (H) that is on Crawley Road.

House I isn't on Crawley Road.  Its entrance is presumably from City Road or possibly from the public gardens.  Even supposing that House I had its own garden with an accompanying entrance on Crawley Road, it still couldn't possibly be the correct answer, because the text states that the house is "next to the footpath that leads to the public gardens".

House H is indeed next to a footpath that leads to the public gardens.  This isn't true of any of the other houses.

It is extraordinarily improbable that any of the roads with arrows of them are counted as part of Crawley Road, but even if they were, none of them have houses on them that are next to the footpath that leads to the public gardens.

In case you missed the fact that Crawley Road is clearly marked, the text also states that Crawley Road is "at the bottom of the map".